# R: Finding extrema of formula generated dynamically from lm()

Tags: r, function, lm, predict

I would like to generate functions from `lm()` models' coefficients and variables and use `nlminb()` to find the extrema. Using `predict()` does not give the resolution I need. The `lm()` models have several dimension.

`x` is my data table. `Y3m5` is a `lm()` model generated by an algorithm called `stepForward`.

Writing a function manually:

```
fY3m5 <- function(Y3model5) {
  -(Y3m5$coefficients[1] + 
    Y3model5[1]*Y3m5$coefficients[2] + 
    Y3model5[2]*Y3m5$coefficients[3] + 
    Y3model5[3]*Y3m5$coefficients[4] + 
    Y3model5[4]*Y3model5[4]*Y3m5$coefficients[5] + 
    Y3model5[4]*Y3m5$coefficients[6] + 
    Y3model5[5]*Y3m5$coefficients[7] + 
    Y3model5[2]*Y3model5[3]*Y3m5$coefficients[8] +
    Y3model5[2]*Y3model5[4]*Y3m5$coefficients[9] + 
    Y3model5[2]*Y3model5[5]*Y3m5$coefficients[10]) 
}
```

and running it through `nlminb()`:

```
nlminb(c(0.0055, 
         0.0018, 
         0.15, 
         0.036,
         0.0425), 
       fY3m5, 
       hessian=NULL, 
       upper = unlist(lapply(x[1:6], max)),
       lower = unlist(lapply(x[1:6], min)))
```

works a treat and gives a meaningful minimum.

Trying, instead, to generate the function dynamically from the `lm()` model,

first defining `starts` as the center (mean) of the space

```
starts <- c("x" = 1, unlist(lapply(x[1:6],mean)))
```

and `repl1` as a string replacement vector

```
repl1 <- c("starts['x']", "", "", "*", "", paste0("starts['", names(x[1:6]), "']"))
names(repl1) <- c("Intercept", "\\)", "\\(", ":", "I", names(x[1:6]))
```

and then making the function from the `lm()` model

```
fY3m5_2 <- function(model, starts) {
  function(starts) {
    noquote(
      paste0("-(",
             paste(
               paste0(
                 str_replace_all(
                   labels(model$coefficients),
                   repl1),
                 "*",
                 "(",
                 model$coefficients,
                 ")"),
               collapse = " + "),
             ")")
    )
  }
}
```

should work IMHO. But doing

```
nlminb(c(0.0055, 
         0.0018, 
         0.15, 
         0.036, 
         0.0425), 
       eval(fY3m5_2(Y3m5,)), 
       hessian=NULL, 
       upper = unlist(lapply(x[1:6], max)),
       lower = unlist(lapply(x[1:6], min)))
```

doesn't give the expected outcome (as writing the function manually did).

I'm surprised at how difficult it's been to find any good clues on this, and the above has taken me a long time to reach. Generating the function edible to nlminb() hasn't been attempted before, as far as I can see. Apologies if I'm wrong. Please help me get over the final hurdle!

Thanks!

Comment: 65 views - no replies. What am I doing wrong?